# How to cross check POST with database

Tags: php, database, validation, pdo

Hi guys I was wondering if they is a way to cross check `select` options getting posted to a different page with a `database` just to make sure that someone hasn't change anything using a inspect element or firebug or any developer tool.

database table `product`

my database looks something like this but they are over 400 data in it.

```
pid   name   size            
1     grey   12 inch          
2     blue   16 inch
```

database table `category`

```
pid    category
1        vans
2        nike
```

database table `itemised`

```
pid      price
1        30.00
2        50.00
```

**item.php**

in my item.php page I have a `table`. The `size` and `category` and SELECT OPTION then I have an input field for `amount` which uses jquery for validation.

in my **cartpage.php**

I Posting  the `pid`, `size` and `category` then I am using all those to find the price(I AM NOT POSTING THE PRICE, I AM USING THE pid, size and category to find it.)

Now the problem is, if someone was to change the `value` for the `size` or `category` or both. They will still get posted but obviously the price `wouldn't` be find because the database can't find those value getting posted.

How I show my value *category example* *similar to how i show size too apart from I change the select statement*

```
    <select id="Category" name="Category">
<?php
        dbconnect(); 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Name FROM Category WHERE pid=:id");
        $stmt->bindParam('id',$id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ) {
        if ($i == 0) {

        echo '<option SELECTED value="'.$row['Name'].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>
        ';
        }
        else {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['Name'].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>';
        }
        $i++;
        }
    ?>
      </select>
```

**My question** 
Is they a way to find out that what is getting posted exist in the database and it is related to the `pid`? and if not that item shouldn't be added.

**Edited to add how my cart page looks like Jim Martens** *I have added the code you show in your answer*
//I have session start on top of this page.

```
<?php
    *jim matens your code starts here*
    if (isset($_GET['pid'])){
    $id = $_GET['ProdID'];

    $categoryID = (isset($_POST['Category']) ? intval($_POST['Category']) : 0);
    dbconnect();
    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT CatID FROM Category WHERE pid=:id");
    $stmt1->bindParam('id',$id);
    $stmt1->execute();

    $isValid = false;
    $rows2 = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($rows2 as $row1) {
        if ($row1['CatID'] == $categoryID) {
            $isValid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    }

      *My code starts here*
    if(isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['length']) && isset($_POST['Qty']) && isset($_POST['Category'])){   
        $pid = $_POST['pid'];
        $length = $_POST["length"];
        $qty = $_POST['Qty'];
        $Category = $_POST['Category'];
        $wasFound = false;

        $i = 0;
        // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
        if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
            // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
            $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "length" => $length, "Category" => $Category, "quantity" => $qty));
        } else {
            // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"]as $array_key=>$each_item) { 
                  if ($each_item['item_id'] == $pid  && $each_item['length'] == $length && $each_item['Category'] == $Category) {
                          $_SESSION["cart_array"][$array_key]['quantity']+=$qty;
                          $wasFound = true;

                      } // close if condition
                  } // close while loop
                // close foreach loop
               if ($wasFound == false) {
                   array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "length" => $length, "Category" => $Category, "quantity" => $qty));

               }
        }
        header('Location: '.fetchinline($bpages).$currentFile);
        exit();
    }
    ?>
```

I hope I have explain this clearly and if not please leave a comment and I will try and rephrase the question.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use a simple loop?

Comment: How do you validate the input? And for the simple loop thing: `while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
// loop content
}`

Comment: @JimMartens for the input I am doing this 
`if (!/^[1-9]\d?$/.test(Qty)){
            alert('Quantity should not be below 1 or null');
            return false; // don't continue
        }`

Comment: @JimMartens well I dont need to loop the select option. dont see the point because what I have in that question works just fine. I was showing it incase someone wanted to know how my select option looks like

Comment: @SarahJames While validating in JavaScript might be a time saver, it is not foolproof. You **have** to validate on server side always. Imagine what would happen if I turn JavaScript off.

And for the loop: My proposal doesn't change your code, it just makes it performance effective. Right now you fetch all the rows for every row in the result set. Another way would be this: `$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); foreach ($rows as $row) { //loop content }`.

Comment: @JimMartens thanks XXX for that :). But for my question how can I verify   what is getting sent to make sure that it exist in the database. bare in mind I am not INSERTing rather just check that the user didnt change any of the values to whatever

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript validation is a nice gimmick for spelling issues and the like. But it is neither foolproof nor able to actually verify if the data is semantically correct. Therefore you need to send the data to the PHP script.

That script now verifies it first for integrity (correct value type and the like). After this initial step you verify against the database in your case. If I understand you correctly, you want to make sure that the sent category is an existing category. There is one very simple way to achieve that.

First your form.

```
<select id="Category" name="Category">
<?php
    dbconnect();
    // select the ID of the category as well (should be there anyway)
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, Name FROM Category WHERE pid=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam('id',$id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $i = 0;
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($i == 0) { ?>
            <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></option>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        $i++;
    }
?>
</select>
```

For the actual processing of the input, you read all categoryIDs from database and check if the selected ID (should be made to integer by now) is among them. If yes, everything's fine, if not the user has given invalid input.

A quick example for that:

```
$categoryID = (isset($_POST['Category']) ? intval($_POST['Category']) : 0);
dbconnect();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID FROM Category WHERE pid=:id");
$stmt->bindParam('id',$id);
$stmt->execute();

$isValid = false;
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($row['ID'] == $categoryID) {
        $isValid = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

ID stands here for the category ID (whatever that is in your case).
Of course your real code would continue before and after this, but it should give you the general direction.

Comment: I have edited the question to add how i add to cart. In that edit i have added your code but the problem is, if I make the value in my category select option empty, and click add to cart. In my cart it will duplicate existing items

Comment: @SarahJames The parameter :id is your pid (as visible). The selected ID is the ID of the category. I assumed that you have a pid (Program ID?) and for each pid you have a bunch of categories with their own names and IDs.

Comment: My category table as `pid` which is a foreign key from product table. `CatID` which is the category id, `size` and `price`. I dont get what you mean here `"The selected ID is the ID of the category. I assumed that you have a pid (Program ID?) "` and yes for each pid they are alot of category and name, each category name as they own unique id which will be the `CatID`

Comment: if u want to see the site. You might be able to understand it better